# Inverse function of $f(x)=x^{2019}+x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let $f: ]0,\infty[ \to]0, \infty[$ and $$f(x)=x^{2019}+x$$
>
> Show that $f$ has an strictly increasing and differentiable inverse function $f^{-1} :]0, \infty[ \to ]0, \infty[.$ Determine the derivative $(f^{-1})'(2).$

How can I show something like this? Since the function is increasing could I just try to show that $f$ is surjective in order to prove the inverse function?

Comment: "could I just try to show that f is bijective in order to prove the inverse function?" This sentence is a bit strange since Bijective = invertible. Since the function is increasing, then it is injective. You only have to show it is **sur**jective, that is the range of $f$ is all $]0,\infty[$. You also need to explain why $f^{-1}$ is differentiable (you certainly have a theorem about that).

Comment: Ah, messed up the terms. Edited.

Comment: Good. I don't know why you got downvoted, that's a valid question. Actually, there is a theorem that answers directly your question, but many students seem to have difficulties with this kind of problems, so it is even a good question. +1.

Comment: I believe the bracket notation for intervals should not have been modified that way. In some areas (France and Mongolia for example), reversed brackets are used to represent an open bracket. For example, $]a,b[$ is the same as $(a,b)$ and $]0,\infty[$ means $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Oh, it's the same from where I'm from $]a, b[$ is equivalent to $(a, b)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Show that $f$ has an strictly increasing and differentiable inverse function $f^{-1} :[0, \infty[ \to [0, \infty[.$ Determine the derivative $(f^{-1})(2).$

There are a few things to do:

1. **Show that $f$ has an inverse**: We have $f'(x)=2019x^{2018}+1 >0$, so $f$ is increasing. In particular, it is injective (aka one-to-one).

   *Note:* We could also have said that $f$ is increasing because it is the sum of two increasing functions, $x^{2019}$ and $x$. But we will need to compute $f'$ anyway.

   Moreover, we have $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=0$, $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\infty$ and $f$ is continuous, so its range is $]0,\infty[$. This means that $f$ is surjective, hence bijective
2. **Show that $f^{-1}$ is increasing**: the inverse of an increasing function is also increasing, so that part is good :)
3. **Show that f is differentiable**: the function $f$ is polynomial, hence it is differentiable. Here comes the important theorem:

> Let $f$ be a differentiable function and $b$ an element of $\textrm{range}(f)=\textrm{dom}(f^{-1})$. Then $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $b$ if and only if $f'(f^{-1}(b))\neq 0$. In that case,
>
> $$\left(f^{-1}\right)'(b)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(b))}$$

Since $f'(x)\geqslant 1$ for every $x>0$, we obtain that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable on its domain.

4. **Compute $f^{-1}(2)$**: don't try to find a formula for $f^{-1}(x)$! This is probably impossible... but it is easy to remark that $f(1)=2$ so $f^{-1}(2)=1$.
5. **Compute $(f^{-1})'(2)$**: we just need to use the formula above:

   $$\left(f^{-1}\right)'(2)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(2))} = \frac{1}{f'(1)}=\frac{1}{2020}$$

Comment: Very nice answer. Especially the remark "don't try to find a formula for $f^{-1}(x)$" is important. Most beginners are used to formula based differentiation and rarely think about definitions and theorems for evaluating derivatives. +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: thanks. I guess the teacher chose a function whose inverse is not elementary to force the students to use the theorem I quoted.